# Linking to Glyphicon Fonts Between Sites (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning to work with Bootstrap. Since I have several websites, I'd like to put the Boostrap style sheets - bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css - on just one site ("mysite.com") and link the other sites to them.

The problem is that when I do that, my glyphicons don't display. I discovered the folder named "fonts," and copied it to mysite.com. Then I found the styles in bootstrap.min.css that I need to change:

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-  regular.eot);src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix)  format('embedded-opentype'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings- regular.woff) format('woff'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf)  format('truetype'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings- regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format('svg')}
```

In fact, it looks like these are the only two that I need to change:

```
url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'),
url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'),
```

But I haven't been able to rewrite the links to make them work. For example, url(http://mysite/css/bootstrap/fonts/glphicons(etc.) doesn't work.

Is it possible to link to glyphicon fonts across sites? If not, another possibility is that I could put the style sheets on mysite.com but copy the fonts to each site, then put these styles in each page's head section, where I can point to the proper directory.

Comment: I had a very similar problem last week, ended up copying the .ttf to my fonts folder and overwriting bootstrap's css with a font-face to reset the path... I understand this is not exactly what you need so get an upvote

Comment: I just put those styles in my head section and couldn't even make that work. Fussy fonts. ;)

Comment: you might want to give a look to something like http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Wow, you're a mind reader! I just discovered that I could make it work by linking to <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> I kind of prefer to have style sheets and JS files on my sites, just in case something happens to the host site. But I can maintain a copy as a backup. Thx.

Comment: you can use a cdn and still have your files as a fallback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font files are subject to cross domain access controls.  You either need to put the font files in each website.  Deactivate the cross domain access controls on the server hosting the font files.  Or configure the server hosting the fonts files to permit access by the domains of your sites.

For apache, you need to set some of the settings in the apache master confiuration file(s) or else in the .htaccess for the domain that serves the font files.  You will have to modify the following to fit your sites.  You will need to have the mod_headers apache module loaded or compiled into the server.

This sets the content types and encodings for the font files.

```
AddType font/truetype .ttf
AddType font/opentype .otf
AddType font/opentype .woff
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddEncoding gzip .svgz
```

This sets the access control to permit access from "sample.com"

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "sample.com"
 </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Naturally different browsers will behave differently, so as always test these changes across all browers possible.   For servers other than Apache, you will have to use their configs to do the same as above.

Replace "sample.com" with your website's url, you can also replace "sample.com" with "*", however doing so, will deactivate controls on font files. It opens your server to provide these files to any other site that may attempt to access them.